# Convert data to be single quoted

Tags: linux, awk

I have a task where I want to convert the below text to single quote text

The data in the file is:

```
(A,1)
(DC,2)
(EFG,3)
```

The output should be like:

```
('A'1)
('DC',2)
('EFG'3)
```

I used `awk -F print '{$2}' > file.txt`

Comment: So do you want the `,` to be dropped in the first and third row of the output?

Comment: Please state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The quoting is a hassle, but `sed -E 's/\(([^,]+)/('\''\1'\''/'` will do what _I think_ you want.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{s1="\047";FS=OFS=","} {sub(/^\(/,"&" s1 );$1=$1 s1} 1' Input_file
```

***Why OP's attempt didn't work:*** Since OP has not defined `F`(field separator) and simply trying to print 2nd column which will be NULL.

Comment: Your solution makes more sense, as output like `('EFG'3)` (as requested) will be hard for another program to parse as fields. BUT the O.P. hasn't answered comments requesting clarification, so be ready to do a rewrite ;-> ! Good luck.